# How can I select several slicer items with an array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, pivot, slicers

I am trying to select several item in a slicer for a pivot table.

I created an array with all items which should be chosen. My code only selects one item.

```
For cnt = UBound(Visible_Both_Years) To 0 Step -1

'filled array
MsgBox Visible_Both_Years(cnt)

'Loop through filter 
With k
    For Each l In .PivotItems
        Select Case l.Name
            Case Is = Visible_Both_Years(cnt)
                l.Visible = True
            Case Else
                l.Visible = False
        End Select
    Next

End With
```

I am a newbie in VBA.

Comment: what is the variable `k` supposed to be here? an `Excel.Worksheet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to loop through your array, try...

```
'Loop through filter
With k
    .ClearAllFilters 'clear any existing filters
    For Each l In .PivotItems
        If IsError(Application.Match(l.Name, Visible_Both_Years, 0)) Then
            l.Visible = False
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, thank you! Sometimes it can be so easy. Much appreciated!